# Is recomended to use BPG to a website?

Tags: images, optimization, compatibility

I want to use [BPG](http://www.gizmag.com/bpg-image-format-outperforms-jpeg/35232/) on my website, but I'm not sure wether the support is broad enough.

- Maybe the javascript plugin for decoding doens't work with all browsers
- Maybe the decoding process consume too much of cpu
- Issues on mobile devices
- SEO effect

Maybe there are already companies using it on their public website.
There is very little info about using this technologie in a real context

**Is it safe to use bpg for a public website with all point that involve?**

([What is BPG?](http://www.gizmag.com/bpg-image-format-outperforms-jpeg/35232/))

Comment: I wouldn't advise it due to its proprietary nature and low market penetration; the small benefits you'd gain in image quality could be offset just by using lower JPEG compression at the cost of slightly more bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment BPG looks promising, but is something I would not use on production websites (yet). Why?

- It requires javascript, so users without javascript have no images.
- Decompression and rendering of the bpg in javascript just takes too
  long especially on mobile devices, even when the javascript and bpg
  are in the browser cache.
- Because the bpg rendering in javascript
  takes so long it also blocks the rendering of other things that are
  normally rendered fast.

If you want see the effects on page rendering yourself see these links, look at the filmstrips, on webpagetest that made runs on some of the bpg demo pages:

- [images of Lena on IE11](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151127_51_GWR/)
- [demo using chrome](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151127_75_GPT/)
- [demo using nexus device](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151127_W4_GRP/)

When browsers get native support then it will be very interesting, but while bpg depends on this slow javascript I would just rely on JPEG and webp.

PS regarding the effect on SEO I don't know.

Comment: Re SEO: Google can execute JavaScript but that doesn't mean it will understand the result. If the plugin converts to a datauri Google won't index it.

Comment: I agree that Google won't be able to detect the bpg as a valid image. So the image will not be indexed. If that will have an adverse effect on the ranking of the html containing the bpg it can't read. I don't know.

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect the ranking of the page itself, besides a very minor hit for speed.